# what Sobolev space does this function belong to?

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

If $u(x,y)$ satisfies
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|u(x,y)|^2dxdy<\infty,\tag{1}$$
then we say $u\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^2)$

If $f(x,y)$ satisfies
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}|y f(x,y)|^2dxdy<\infty.\tag{2}$$

Then $f(x,y)\in ?$

Comment: I wouldn't call this would be a Sobolev space, but moreso a weighted $L^2$ space perhaps?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Let $g(x,y)$ be the Fourier transform of $h(x,\eta)$, then do we have $||\partial_{\eta} h||_{L^2}=||y g(x,y)||_{L^2}$?